# Login batch working only after duplicate run

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

So i'm trying to make a simple script (path and program name is not important, because it's "running"):

```
kill\pv.exe -kf myprogram*.exe
kill\pv.exe -kf myprogram1*.exe
xcopy \\nt\folder.drv\myprogram\new\*.* "c:\myprogram" /s /e /h /r /d /y

if errorlevel 0 myprogram.exe & wscript login.vbs
```

I made also a "login" vbscript:

```
set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WSCript.shell")

wscript.sleep 1000
wshShell.sendkeys "password"
wscript.sleep 2000
wshShell.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit
```

So, if i run the .bat file once, the program is starting.. but somehow "vbscript" is not working. So it is not logging in.

IF i start once more the .bat file (while the old one is running), the program runs.. and also the scipt "gives" the password and "hits" enter.. Any ideas what's going on ?

Comment: `if errorlevel 0` means `If the errorlevel is 0 OR GREATER THAN ZERO` so `myprogram.exe etc. ` will *always* run. Try `if not errorlevel 1 ...` to detect `errorlevel = 0`

Comment: @Magoo yep, that's right! Thanks. But the "error" is still there.. if i run this script once, it doesn't fill the requiered "password field".. if i run it once more, it works.

Comment: Have you looked at the value of `%errorlevel%`  in both instances? Is `XCOPY` actually setting `errorlevel`, or are you seeing the `errorlevel` set by `pv.exe` in the previous step? Where does `program1` come into the scenario? You appear to start `program,exe` twice, but `program1` is only mentioned in the second `pv.exe`.

Comment: "**start /d**" solved my problem.

Comment: @Magoo Yes, pv.exe has errorlevel (0). XCOPY also setting errorlevel, which is 0, too.